# Java WebStart custom secuity policy ignored

Tags: java-web-start, javapolicy

I am trying to trace an issue in one of our client software with aspectJ.
The software is deployed via an jnlp file.

I try to launch the application with `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`

```
-Djava.security.policy==path\to\all.policy
```

Where `all.policy` contains

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

but on launch I still get AccessControlException.

Launching with `-Djava.security.debug=policy` shows that only the system policy files `javaws.policy` and `java.policy` get recognized.

Why does my custom policy not get recognized?